# Python doesn't recognize the existance of a class parameter

Tags: python

I'm working on a text based RPG game in python, and I have a class that tracks time of day, passage of seasons over time, ect... among other things, it cycles through different moon cycles (28 moon, full, new, etc... like in the real world). The class Date_Time()'s **init** function includes the statement self.moon_state = 0, but the function I wrote to test some of the methods related to the moon returns the error: "AttributeError: 'Date_Time' object has no attribute 'moon_state'"
here's the **init** function:

```
def __inti__(self, environment, season=Spring()):

    #### Objects ####
    self.season = season
    self.environment = environment
    self.weather = environment.weather
    self.player = environment.player

    #### time ####
    self.time_of_day = 0
    self.day_of_season = 0
    self.year = 0

    self.moon_state = 0
```

and the test code:

```
for k in range(50):
    date_time.cycle_moon(1)
    print("\n ---- test moon", k + 1, "------------")
    print("Moon state", date_time.moon_state)
    date_time.check_moon()
    print("Moonlight:", date_time.get_moonlight)
    print(" ---- end test ------------\n")
```

and the function being tested:

def cycle_moon(self, days_passed):
        """advances the moon the given amount of states, wrapping it to 0 when it
        reaches 28 (moon_states go from 0-27)"""

```
    self.moon_state = self.moon_state + days_passed

    while self.moon_state >= 28:
        self.moon_state = self.moon_state - 28
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. The bug makes about as little sense to me as a bug can, the variable exists, but but the interpreter just seems to ignore it.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. I clearly need to work on my debugging skills, that was a pretty basic mistake.... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply, you have a syntax/spelling error.
It should be `__init__` not `__inti__`

The interpreter has no problem with have a `__inti__` method however, nothing is initialized when you create an instance of the class since the interpreter cannot find the `__init__` method